# How to extract longest word from an array? JavaScript/JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I want to create a function that takes a string as its parameter and extracts the longest word. If there are multiple words of the same length (max), It extracts the first one. (By the way, the function ignores numbers and punctuation). Anyways, here's the code:

```js
function extractLongest(testString){
  var lenArr = [];
  var finalResult = "";

window.onload = function(){
  testString = testString.replace(/[^a-z " "]/gi, '');
  testString = testString.split(" ");

  for (var counter = 0; counter < testString.length; counter++){
    lenArr[counter] = parseInt(testString[counter].length);
  }
  lenArr = lenArr.sort();
  for (var counterTwo = 0; counterTwo < testString.length; counterTwo++){
    if(parseInt(testString[counterTwo].length) == Math.max(...lenArr)){
      finalResult = testString[counterTwo];
      break;
    }
  }
 }
return finalResult;
}
```

The problem is that it always returns "string" (the type of the variable, not its value.)

Comment: Your last paragraph does nothing other than (a) earn your question being ignored by people who might otherwise help, (b) inflame anyone who reads it, (c) get you downvotes (I did not).  May I suggest you remove it, and instead politely state that you have researched.  Also, your question _does not_ contain an [mcve] - which is also likely earning you downvotes.  An mcve would include a sample array of strings, and a clear indication of the desired output.

Comment: You should consider editing the question to remove the demand people answer your bloody question. That's not a great way to to ask people to donate their time to helping you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of `window.onload` inside a function. This is only setting the handler on the window, which will only run when an `onload` event fires. Your function does this and then immediately returns `finalReuslts` which will still be an empty string. Presumably, you want all this code to run when you call the function. It's not clear why you are doing that; removing it makes the function work:

```js
function extractLongest(testString){
  var lenArr = [];
  var finalResult = "";

  testString = testString.replace(/[^a-z " "]/gi, '');
  testString = testString.split(" ");
  
  for (var counter = 0; counter < testString.length; counter++){
    lenArr[counter] = parseInt(testString[counter].length);
  }
  lenArr = lenArr.sort();
  for (var counterTwo = 0; counterTwo < testString.length; counterTwo++){
    if(parseInt(testString[counterTwo].length) == Math.max(...lenArr)){
      finalResult = testString[counterTwo];
      break;
    }
  }
 
return finalResult;
}

console.log(extractLongest("hello my name is stephen"))
```

In case it's useful, there is a simpler way to do this with `reduce()`:

```js
function extractLongest(testString){
  testString = testString.replace(/[^a-z " "]/gi, '');
  testString = testString.split(" ");
  return testString.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.length > b.length ? a : b
});
}
console.log(extractLongest("hello my designation is stephen"))
```